# CameraX Image Analysis app not running the analyze method

Tags: java, android, image-processing, camera, raspberry-pi3

I am developing a camerax app for the image analysis use case. I built it and ran on my phone and it worked perfectly. I also tried it on a few other phones and it worked on them too. We actually plan to use the app on our raspberry pi 3B which has lineageOS installed and has necessary cameras attached and we have also tried running other apps that use camera on it and it worked perfectly. But, when I ran our app on it, it started, showed the animation that it was supposed to show and nothing else happened, like the app didn't crash, we also noticed the camera turning on and off a few times, but that's it. From the logs, I could see the app never runs the code in the setAnalyzer() block. Here's the code for the relevant part.

```
        model=new LocalModel.Builder()
                .setAssetFilePath("model.tflite")
                .build();

        CustomImageLabelerOptions customImageLabelerOptions=new CustomImageLabelerOptions.Builder(model)
                .setConfidenceThreshold(.98f)
                .setMaxResultCount(1)
                .build();

        labeler= ImageLabeling.getClient(customImageLabelerOptions);

        analysis=new ImageAnalysis.Builder().setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
                .build();

        Log.i(TAG, "before the analysis starts");

        analysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), image -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "Analysis started");
            int rotationDegrees = image.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees();
            @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError") Image mediaImage=image.getImage();
            if(mediaImage!=null){
                InputImage i=InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, rotationDegrees);

                labeler.process(i).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<ImageLabel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull @NotNull List<ImageLabel> imageLabels) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "successfully started to process the image");
                        String labels="";
                        for(ImageLabel label: imageLabels){
                            Log.i(TAG, label.getText());
                            labels=label.getText();
                            Log.i(TAG, labels);
                        }

                        if(labels.equalsIgnoreCase("dew")) {
                            isDetectingBottles=true;
                            d.stop();
                            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unnffffamed);
                        }
                        else{
                            if(isDetectingBottles){
                                isDetectingBottles=false;
                                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blink_animation);
                                d= (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
                                d.start();
                            }
                        }
                        image.close();
                    }


                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "ImageLabeling process failed");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        image.close();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        CameraSelector selector= CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA;

        Log.i(TAG, "before binding to lifecycle");

        ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> m=ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        m.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               try {
                   m.get().bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) MainActivity.this, selector, analysis);
               }
               catch(InterruptedException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               catch(ExecutionException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
```

Here are a few thing I tried:

1. At the beginning I didn't set any target resolution and left it to camerax but it still didn't work back then.
2. I tried using different cameras with the selector, using the front camera leads to a crash.
3. Tried calling image.close() at the end of setAnalyzer block, but that's obviously not the issue since it works on other devices.

NOTE: the logs don't show any exceptions as for me to get an idea of what's happening.

Comment: what happens if you change `ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)` in `analysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), image -> {` with `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` ?

Comment: no changes, still behaving the same way

Comment: @Talha Did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same issue on Android x86 and my preview grinds to a halt, looks like the camera constantly resets itself.